# react-wp-theme is not giving error with packages running on ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created react-wp-theme using npx create-wp-theme, recently I have added @aws-amplify/ui-react-geo package which index file extension is .mjs

It is giving the following error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react-geo/dist/esm/components/MapView/MapView.mjs 20:13-14 
Can't import the named export 'useState' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react-geo/dist/esm/index.mjs
 @ ./src/pages/test/Test.jsx
 @ ./src/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi ./src/index.js
```

It is working after change the node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react-geo/dist/esm/index.mjs to index.js but I cannot change it in production. Could you please help why it is giving issues on mjs files

**I have added webpack.config.js file also in root where package.json file is exist**

```
export default config = {
    mode: 'development', // "production" | "development" | "none"
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['*', '.mjs', '.js', '.json']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.mjs$/,
          include: /node_modules/,
          type: 'javascript/auto'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**package.json dependencies object**

```
"dependencies": {
        "@aws-amplify/ui-react-geo": "^1.0.0",
        "@devloco/react-scripts-wptheme": "^3.4.1-wp.1",
        "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.18.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
        "aws-amplify": "^5.2.5",
        "axios": "^1.3.6",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "dotenv": "^16.1.4",
        "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
        "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-azure-maps": "^0.4.7",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
        "react-map-gl": "^7.0.25",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
        "react-slider": "^2.0.4"
    },
```